# How to add TabBarItem to default TabBarController without setting it as ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, uistoryboard

I'm not using a custom `TabBarContoller`. Instead of this, i created a `TabBarController` on storyboard and add my `ViewControllers` from there. However i need to bind a `TabBarItem` with `UIImagePicker` just like clicking button to open `UIImagePicker`, so there is no need to add another empty `ViewController` i guess..

I'm not able to drag and drop a new `TabBarItem` it to `TabBarController`. Is there a way to do this without implementing a custom `TabBarController` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that -- the tab bar items come from the content controllers, not directly from the tab bar controller. You'll have to add a separate controller, from which you can launch the image picker in its viewDidAppear method, so it will show up as soon as you switch to that tab.

Comment: hmm..i understand but when i dismiss imagepicker at the end of the taking the photo or canceling it, viewDidAppear will be executed again. even if i set a flag as isFlowFinished , it will be become more complicated because after selecting the picture, there are another controllers come in with their navigation controllers. At the end of the whole picking and processing i need to return my first controller. i think the flag thing will make the flow more complicated.. Can you suggest a way to make it simple?

Comment: @hgoz, it's hard to advise without knowing your controller structure, but if you launch it from viewDidAppear, then you will have to use a flag of some sort. If you want it to return to the first controller when everything is done, then that's the controller you should launch it from. If you're several controllers into a navigation stack when you want to go back to the first controller, then you could use an unwind segue to go back in one step.

Comment: ahh, segues! great idea to perform segue and make the navigation stack clear at the end of the flow. thank you!